# Order of growth determination

Tags: algorithm

I am practicing order of growth and I was having trouble determining the order of growth for the following function:

```
def ri(na):
    if na <= 1:
         return na
    def han(na):
         i = 1
         while i < na:
             i *= 2
         return i
    return ri(na/2) + ri(na/2) + han(na-2)
```

I believe the function han has an order of growth $\Theta(n) = log(n)$ but I'm not sure how to think about this when adding ri(na/2). I would appreciate if anyone can help me out in figuring out how to compute the run time. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of `han` function is `Theta(log(n))` (each time `i` is mulplied by `2`). Hence, the time complexity of `ri` is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Theta(log(n))`. Using [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) we can say `T(n) = Theta(n)`.

Comment: Thanks! I had heard before of the master theorem, but completely forgot about it! I will check it out!